# Importing defined functions from one .py file to another .py file in Django

Tags: python, django, import

I am trying to create a website and I have my html working 100% on a local host using django.

At the moment my code is not associated with the html so if I put in a username and password, the page does nothing, which makes sense.

I am at the point where I am trying to import a defined function from my `.py` file with all my code(`b.py`) and I have another file (`a.py`) which essentially should take the information from the defined functions of `b.py`, use the information, then display it on the localhost webpage.

But my issue is that it is saying `ImportError: cannot import name 'definedfunctionname'`. Both `a.py` and `b.py` are in the same directory as each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your a.py file:

```
from b import definedfunction

# Call 
definedfunction()
```

Alternatively:

```
import b

# Call it as below
b.definedfunction()
```

Comment: Okay that got rid of not being able to import name. Now since I am not using manage.py to run this on a local host but instead putting the line app=django(__name__) to initiate it, I get an error, so how would I initiate the local host in the same file I just imported in?

Comment: What error are you getting? This sounds like a next question not related to your initial problem.